# About using bootstrap

Tags: python, html, django, twitter-bootstrap

I was hoping to use [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) in my project where users would only have to write html code relating with the Bootstrap's `classes /ids` for their blog. And would only allow html tags using `python's` module [bleach](https://django-bleach.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). So my question:

1. Is Bootstrap ok for commercial use? I know it is, but I don't know whether mine will be just commercial or distribution. Will I be able to use Bootstrap for the above purpose?
2. Is it OK to use it? Are their any security issues for this?

I would really appreciate if you could guide me through. Thank you!

Comment: not really a programming question, more of a legal question no?

Answer (score 1):

This is not exactly a programming question but I will bite:

http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#license-faqs

### It requires you to:

- Include the license and copyright notice in your works

### It permits you to:

- ***Freely download and use Bootstrap, in whole or in part, for personal,
  private, company internal, or commercial purposes***
- Use Bootstrap in packages or distributions that you create
- Modify the source code
- Grant a sublicense to modify and distribute Bootstrap to third
  parties not included in the license

### It forbids you to:

- Hold the authors and license owners liable for damages as Bootstrap
  is provided without warranty
- Hold the creators or copyright holders of Bootstrap liable
- Redistribute any piece of Bootstrap without proper attribution
- Use any marks owned by Twitter in any way that might state or imply
  that Twitter endorses your distribution
- Use any marks owned by Twitter in any way that might state or imply
  that you created the Twitter software in question

### It does not require you to:

- Include the source of Bootstrap itself, or of any modifications you
  may have made to it, in any redistribution you may assemble that
  includes it
- Submit changes that you make to Bootstrap back to the Bootstrap
  project (though such feedback is encouraged)

***The full Bootstrap license is located in the project repository for more information.***

## As it relates to security

Bootstrap is simply a collection of visual style aids and some helper javascript classes to assist those visual aids.  Note also that some jquery is used.  Security wise you are in pretty good shape using this library.